# XMLHttpRequest is not defined - Papa parse

Tags: javascript, papaparse

EDIT: [SOLVED] For anyone who reads this, Papa Parse is a parser for the browser, not Node.js. Baby Parse is used for Node.js, but know that it isn't as extensive in its functionality and can't parse straight from a file, only from a string.

In the `papaparse.js` file, it has this line of code:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

This seems to be causing the error and I'm not sure how to get around it.

My code:

```
var Papa = require('papaparse');
var data;

process.argv.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
    console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
var file = process.argv[2];
console.log("File: " + file);


// Parse the file
Papa.parse(file, {
    header: true,
    download: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: function(results) {
        data = results;
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to run browser Javascript in Node.js.  You can't do that.

Comment: you could also use babyparse that is commonjs https://github.com/Rich-Harris/BabyParse

Comment: Yup, you're absolutely right. Papa parse is for the browser, and I just found out Baby Parse is for node. I see the issue now, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

actually PapaParse can be used in a node environment now:
https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/README.md#papa-parse-for-node

however, you have to disable the "download" option in the parse-config, since otherwise the library will attempt to load the file via XMLHttpRequest.